# Symfony call Command from controller as background task

Tags: symfony

I want to run a Symfony Console Command from a controller. How to do so is explained in the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/console/command_in_controller.html).

Now my controller waits until the Command is finished. But I want the Command to be executed as a background task (like a cronjob). So the controller doesn't need to wait to complete the Command, only start it.

Is this possible with Symfony Console?

Comment: You have to use queuing mechanism. https://github.com/php-amqplib/RabbitMqBundle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have to use [Process component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html#running-processes-asynchronously) and launch command like that:

```
$process = new Process('php bin/console your:command');
$process->start();
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need! I also was looking for `exec()`, but this has way more functions.

Comment: This does not work, in symfony 4 is there a new way to do it ??

Comment: I took this example from symfony 4 docs, and I used this code in my projects based on Symfony 4. And it worked. Are you sure that you use `start` instead of `run`?

Comment: Hello I tried `use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;


$process = new Process('php bin/console app:import:records' . '  > NUL');
$process->run();
return new Response('successfully done', Response::HTTP_OK);`  it returns response only but the command in between is not executed. Can anybody help?

Comment: @nas why using run() and not start()? start() works fine and was suggested.

Comment: @CalamityJane start didnot worked as expected.